# Double quotes and NSPredicates

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wondering why my predicates are having double quotes around the whatDateShouldEqual and the whatDateShouldEqual2 strings? is there a way to get rid of them in the predicate? I'm getting my predicate string equaling.

> "whatDateShouldEqual" >= CAST(378720000.000000, "NSDate");

The double quotes are messing up my predicate.

```
//This method calls the function
- (NSArray *) getAllTasksForCurrentYearForPieChart
{
    NSArray *yearToDatePredicates = [self getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"timeSheetDate"] secondPredicateFilterAtrribute:@"timeSheetDate"];

    NSArray *allTimeSheets = [self getTimeSheetsWithEmployeeId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[CANetworkingManager sharedCANetworkingManager].employeeId  intValue]]];

    NSPredicate *predicate =  [yearToDatePredicates objectAtIndex:0];
    [allTimeSheets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    predicate = [yearToDatePredicates objectAtIndex:1];
    [allTimeSheets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *uniqueTaskIds = [self getAllUniqueTaskIDsBasedOnArrayOfTimeSheets:allTimeSheets];

    NSArray *uniqueTasks = [self getTasks];

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskID IN %@", uniqueTaskIds];
    uniqueTasks = [uniqueTasks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return uniqueTasks;
}



 - (NSArray *) getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions: (NSString *) whatDateShouldEqual
                      secondPredicateFilterAtrribute: (NSString *) whatDateShouldEqual2
    {
        // This will get the task within the time area
        NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd"];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSInteger year = [components year];

        NSDate *firstDayOfYear = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d 01 01", year]];
        NSDate *currentDayOfYear = [NSDate date];

        NSMutableArray *holdBothPredicates = [NSMutableArray new];

        [holdBothPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= %@", whatDateShouldEqual, firstDayOfYear]];

        [holdBothPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ <= %@", whatDateShouldEqual2, currentDayOfYear]];

        NSArray *turningToArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:holdBothPredicates];

        return turningToArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substitute a *key* in a predicate string you have to use the `%K` format specifier:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K >= %@", whatDateShouldEqual, firstDayOfYear]
```

Comment: The %K says it's an invalid conversion

Comment: In which line do you get that error? - How is the array returned by this method used?

Comment: I'm trying to filter an existing array with both of the predicates... it's when I used the line

[existingArray filterArrayUsingPredicate: [predicateArray objectAtIndex: 0]];

This is where it breaks

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Can you `NSLog(@"%@", [predicateArray objectAtIndex: 0])` at that point?

Comment: "whatDateShouldEqual" >= CAST(378720000.000000, "NSDate");

the surrounding double quotes around the whatDateShouldEqual is whats messing it up

Comment: @MichaelChoi: It should be `xxx >= CAST(...)` where xxx is the *contents* of the whatDateShouldEqual variable. - What does this variable contain? Did you really use %K at the right place? Do you use any other functions to modify the predicates returned by your method?

Comment: That why it's weird the variable is just a string I call the function like

- (NSArray *) getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions: @"hey"
                      secondPredicateFilterAtrribute: @"hey2"

I tried the %K in the predicate like you said and it had an invalid conversion problem and no I didn't modify the returned array at all.

Comment: @MichaelChoi: When I call your method (with the %K modification) as `[self getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions:@"hey" secondPredicateFilterAtrribute:@"hey2"]` then I get back an array of two predicates: `hey >= CAST(378687600.000000, "NSDate")` and `hey2 <= CAST(398380434.750796, "NSDate")`.

Comment: I get predicate: K >= hey

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Then your function is different from what you posted in your question. I took exactly your code, only that the first %@ in each predicate is replaced by %K.

Comment: I am using xCode 5 DP 5 if that is different from yours

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Perhaps you can post more code, from the call of `getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions:...` until `[existingArray filterArrayUsingPredicate:...]`. - And no, Xcode 5 does not make a difference.

Comment: - (NSArray *) getAllTasksForCurrentYearForPieChart
{
    NSArray *yearToDatePredicates = [self getPredicateForYearToDateFunctions:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"timeSheetDate"] secondPredicateFilterAtrribute:@"timeSheetDate"];
    
    NSArray *allTimeSheets = [self getTimeSheetsWithEmployeeId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[CANetworkingManager sharedCANetworkingManager].employeeId  intValue]]];
    
    NSPredicate *predicate =  [yearToDatePredicates objectAtIndex:0];
    [allTimeSheets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: @MichaelChoi: With back ticks. But you can add that code to your *question*, that would be better readable. - Can you please add the following to the *end* of your getPredicate... method: `NSLog(@"1=%@, 2=%@, 3=%@", whatDateShouldEqual, whatDateShouldEqual2, turningToArray);`.

Comment: Your NSLog Statement gets

 1=timeSheetDate, 2=timeSheetDate, 3=(
    "\"timeSheetDate\" >= CAST(378720000.000000, \"NSDate\")",
    "\"timeSheetDate\" <= CAST(398381941.843485, \"NSDate\")"

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Then you have *not* replaced %@ by %K.

Comment: That my original code for the original question. I did modify it to the %K and it didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Please try %K again. What do you get now for `NSLog(@"1=%@, 2=%@, 3=%@", whatDateShouldEqual, whatDateShouldEqual2, turningToArray);`?

Comment: It seems to be working now. HAHA Thanks a lot for %K works but I swear my manager and I both tried it before and it wasn't working. Thanks for your time.